When running in VSC with cmake the compiler returns that I have an undefined reference to a function
I have a function which is supposed to receive a value from the user then run a function on it which is in another file.
I create a cmake file which is supposed to compile everything and a header which has the function.
Update: The program does not run when I run it through the regular vsc run button. It only runs when I am in the cmake tab.
When I run it normally I get the error:

C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\rivir\AppData\Local\Temp\cc46K6Dm.o:Main.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `addStuff'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My code is below
//Main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Hello.h"

int main(){
    int x;
    int a;
    x = 0;
    char list[1];
    printf("hey");
    printf("\n put in a num");
    gets(list);
    a = (int)list[0];
    x = addStuff(a);
    printf("\n num is %d", x);
    printf("\n done");
    return 0;
}


//Hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Hello.h"

int addStuff(int a){
    return 5+a;
}

//Hello.h
int addStuff(int a);

//CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

project(Hello)
include_directories(include)

add_executable(MyExec
  src/Main.c
  src/Hello.c
  include/Hello.h
)

I have tried to change up my cmake file a few different times, but it isn't working, could anyone help?
I also tried changing my header to what is below, and that didn't work.
//Header
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int addStuff(int a);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
``


Add header guards in hello.h:  #ifndef HELLO_H #define HELLO_H  /* header contents */ #endif

I don't think that is the issue, because even when I call directly from hello.c using include "hello.c" it doesn't work. Also using header guards return an error saying hello.exe is not valid for this os platform.

It isn't the issue, just good practice. I would suspect that your issue is related to linking.

I know that, I was just writing this basic program to see if cmake was working, as I usually use linux when using c. Thought I would try to make the switch to vsc on windows and lo and behold it isn't working.

I also think it is related to linking, just have no clue how.

@Victoria " it works until it has to access the function, where it crashes" --> int x; ... scanf("%d", x); is a coding problem.  Enable all compiler warnings to see why.

how would i do that in visual studio code?

An update: I have gone over a few things and am pretty sure the issue is my cmake file, I am pretty sure something is wrong with what I wrote, so if anyone could help I would really appreciate that :)

How are you telling Code to use cmake?

Add to the question post the complete error message: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

You are using C files, but turning on cxx_20 compile features, hmm. Are you using GCC or g++ as your compiler?

I am using gcc I believe
